# please provide me with a mapping and proper trasnformation in detail

Tags: mapping, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

**Source**

```
Id,name
1,Andrew
2,john
3,Robert
```

**Target**

```
detail
((1/Andrew)(2/john)(3/Robert))
```

please provide solution for the above scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stack Overflow can help you debug your attempts, but it won't magic up a complete answer from nothing.  Show what you have tried so far and why it doesn't work, and someone may be able to help you debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In expression transformation, you can do as following:

ID (I) - ID

Name (I) - Name

v_EXP (V) - v_EXP||'('||ID||'/'||Name||')'

o_EXP (O) - v_EXP

Then link this exp transformation to aggregator transformation which will assign '(1/Andrew)(2/john)(3/Robert)' to o_EXP. Then push it through exp transformation again and do the following:

o_EXP (O) - '(' ||o_EXP || ')'

Answer (score 1):

***Source -> SQ -> EXP -> Agg -> Target***

**In Expression Transformation**

create 3 ports

ID(I) - ID

Name(I) - Name

V_exp(V) -  v_O||'('||**ID**||'/'|| **Name**||')'

V_O (V) - V_exp

O_Result(O) - '('||v_exp||')'

Pass above (O) port to aggregator transformation and then to Target